# Decidability of a given grammar if it is regular

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars, undecidability

According to my course the question "Is $L(G)$ regular?" undecidable. But I was more interested in knowing the exact algorithm or proof that makes this question undecidable. To further elaborate what I mean it is like saying "Is 2 bigger than 1?" is pretty much decidable intuitively because $2 = 1 +1$.

Comment: For context-free grammars, it's a simple result of [Greibach's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem). If you were interested in arbitrary grammars, see Rice's theorem.

Comment: @rici, would you be willing to write that as an answer, so we can upvote it?  I think those two sentences are plenty sufficient to be an answer.  I think the Stack Exchange model tries to discourage answering in a comment and instead encourage putting that as an answer.

Comment: @D.W.: the model also discourages link-only answers, and I was in a bit of a rush in the morning, but I take your point. I'll add something.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!  Personally I think your comment would have been sufficient as an answer too -- I don't see it as a link-only answer.  A way to recognize a link-only answer is, if you remove the link and there is no value left, then that is a problem.  In your case, I think identifying it as Greibach's theorem has value even without the link, but I can see why you were reluctant.  Sorry to give you a hard time, and thank you for your excellent answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undecidability is counter-intuitive at the best of times, and proofs of undecidability might feel unsatisfying at first glance, since they are necessarily non-constructive. (How can you construct an algorithm for something which has no algorithm?)

The basis for a lot of undecidability proofs is [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), which basically says that for any non-trivial semantic property $P$, there is no algorithm which can determine whether an arbitrary program has that property. ($P$ is non-trivial if there is at least one program which satisfies it and at least one program which doesn't satisfy it.) We usually represent programs as Turing Machines, here, since any program can be rewritten as a Turing Machine (although it might not be a practical endeavour). I'm not going to attempt a precise definition of "semantic property" —you can read the Wikipedia page or look at some of the references— but it basically refers to any property which requires running the program.

Here's it's useful to note that any Turing Machine can be represented as a general grammar which derives precisely those inputs which the Turing Machine would accept.

You might think that you can avoid the pathological cases by restricting the grammar to being context-free, but it turns out that even though context-free grammars are a lot easier to reason about than general grammars, there is still no way to tell whether the language recognised by an arbitrary context-free grammar is regular. Nor is there an algorithm to tell whether a context-free grammar recognises every sentence produced with a given alphabet. These two statements were proven in 1963 by [Sheila Greibach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem); the linked Wikipedia page summarizes her elegant proof.